# Generate table using random subset of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently this script takes the words from the list and generates a grid, giving the words random positions each time. When the words are generated I want them to be split into individual characters, into cells next to each other - how do I do this?

```
  var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can",  "man", ];
  var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0, 12);
  shuffledWords.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

 var table = $('<table class="tablestyle">');
 var rows = 6;
 var cols = 2;
 var tr;
 var index;

for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
tr = $('<tr>');
for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
    index = (row * cols) + col;
    $('<td>').text(shuffledWords[index]).appendTo(tr);
}
tr.appendTo(table);
}

 table.appendTo('body');

 $('<table>' + innerTable + '</table>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sorting the list randomly before slicing it. Like this

```
listOfWords.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0, 12);
```

Comment: Using `sort` like this isn't a good idea. It expects that the comparison function returns the same result for the same parameters, which can lead to unintended and difficult to find bugs.

Comment: The sort function is just copied from above. All that was changed was the order.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html = "<table border='0' width='100%'>";
html += "<tr> <td> Search ID </td> <td> Name </td> <td>Location</> <td> Reason </td></tr>"
html += "<tr> <td> 1 </td> <td> Bob </td> <td>Glasgow</> <td> Hello </td></tr>"
html+="</table>";

$('#outputID').append(html);
</script>
```

Where it says

```
<td> Bob </td>
```

replace it with

```
"<td>" + varibleName + "</td>"
```

And the varible name could be each character? Just put this in a loop that suits?

Hope this helps